# find an object in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I use JQuery, backbone, & underscore js.
I have an `Object` containing the array of `objects`. Each object in Array contains some unique id.

Now, I have some 'id' and I'm sure that this id belongs to one of the objects present inside Array of `Objects`.

Now the question is , I want to pass this id and get back the related object. How do i do that?

please advice.

Comment: Why do you mark question as -ve ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, I use underscore find function.

```
var result = _.find(myArray ,function(obj) {
    return obj.id == myId;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

While working with underscorejs you can use the following example

```
var evens = _.filter([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], function(num){ return num % 2 == 0; });
=> [2, 4, 6]
```

As you want to filter object of array, try the following example

```
var YouKeyValue = SomeValue;// Replace SomeValue with value you need

var YourDesiredResult = _.filter(YourObjectArray, function(a){ // YourDesiredResult fills with your result
    return a.id == YouKeyValue ;
});
```

Hope it helps....

Answer (score -1):

If you are using jquery ,you can use [grep](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) function to solve your problem.